# Method access and non exported package

Tags: java, osgi

I have an OSGi bundle with two packages:

1. `com.organization.api` this package is exported.
2. `com.organization.internal` this package is not exported.

In `com.organization.api` I have an interface `Foo` and class `AsbtractFoo`

```
package com.organization.api;

public abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo {

   private int state;

   @Override
   public int getState(){ 
       return this.state; 
   }
}
```

In `com.organization.internal` I have a class `FooManager` that needs to change state of the Foo. How to do it with the the condition that any other classes outside `com.organization.internal` can't change state of foo.

```
package com.organization.internal;

public class FooManager {

   private ???? foo = ....

   public void updateFooState(){
      foo.????();
   }
}
```

I tried to add `AbstractStatefullFoo` with setter of default access (`void setState(int state)`) to package `com.organization.internal` and make `AbstractFoo` extend `AbstractStatefullFoo` but the problem is that this case other bundles require package `com.organization.internal` be exported.

How can such problem solved in OSGi?

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling you are thinking to complex with all those abstract classes.

The simplest case is to have an interface Foo with getState. 
You then have an implementation of Foo in the internal package.

This case does not require other bundles to have access to the impl class in internal. The key point is to also have an interface for FooManager in the api package.

You then create FooManagerImpl that implements FooManager and export it as a service with the interface. Other bundles can then use this service to call the updateState() method and other methods that manipulate FooImpl classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really need abstract classes as they contain very much implementation which is inherited in concrete classes in other bundles.

Comment: You can also do this with abstract classes in between. The key is to use an OSGi service and have other bundles only use classes from the api package.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer.

Something that might simplify things for you is if you encapsulate the mutable foo state, and expose a factory as a service. It might be sensible to have the foo manager service be the factory, in order to make sure that they stay in sync.

The FooState implementation can provide methods for changing the state which are not included in the interface and which are private to the implementation bundle. The FooState interface should be marked as being not for Consumer implementation.

The Foo interface can be changed to allow access to the FooState. This object is read only (unless reflection is used), but is not properly immutable. You could add the access method directly to Foo, or you could create an extra, exported  interface to avoid complicating the interface for API users who don't care about this. 
The AbstractFoo implementation, can be moved to a separate, exported package. This can be nice if the default implementation is likely to sprout  protected methods and generally change more rapidly than the API  itself, you won't have to bump the version of the API as frequently.

The abstract class can take care of getting  a FooState  along with the other implementation support tasks.

There can be a few extra  complications  if you need to be able to update the manager implementation without updating the Foos, but this does not seem to be a  requirement.